# Discord processing commands synchronously and replying to everyone at once. (using discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My discord bot seems to be processing all requests one after the other and replies to everyone at once when all the processing is finished, example :

user A requested to download a video
user B requested to download a video
process A's request
process B's request
reply to A and B.

Whereas, I think that it should process and reply to both the users independently.

**Code:**

```
if clean_content[0] == "!get": #Get complete video (!get link)
        try: 
            yt = pytube.YouTube(clean_content[1])

            if yt.length > time_limit:
                await message.channel.send(f"Length of given video exceeds {time_limit//60} minutes, which is currently unsupported.")
                return 

            await get_func(message, yt)

            return    

        except:
            await message.reply("Some error occured :(")
            return

async def get_func(message,yt):
    yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().download(output_path="./videos",filename=f"down_{message.author}")

    main_folder = new_mega.find('discord_videos')
    file = new_mega.upload(f"./videos/down_{message.author}", main_folder[0])
    os.remove(f"./videos/down_{message.author}")
    
    print(f"processed {message.author}")
    await message.reply(f"File is only valid for {delete_time//3600} hour(s), link : {new_mega.get_upload_link(file)}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.
I used the threading library and created a new thread for processing every new task, as suggested by DJ Walkzz.

**New Code:**

```
if clean_content[0] == "!get": #Get complete video (!get link) 
        
        try: 
            yt = pytube.YouTube(clean_content[1])

            if yt.length > time_limit:
                await message.channel.send(f"Length of given video exceeds {time_limit//60} minutes, which is currently unsupported.")
                return 

            t1 = threading.Thread(target=get_func, args=(message, yt))
            t1.start()

            return       

        except:
            await message.reply("Some error occured :(")
            return

def get_func(message,yt):

    yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().download(output_path="./videos",filename=f"down_{message.author}")

    main_folder = new_mega.find('discord_videos')
    file = new_mega.upload(f"./videos/down_{message.author}", main_folder[0])
    os.remove(f"./videos/down_{message.author}")
    
    print(f"processed {message.author}")

    client.loop.create_task(message.reply(f"File is only valid for {delete_time//3600} hour(s), link : {new_mega.get_upload_link(file)}"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the threading when you call the get_func there you can use threading so it will run in background and when process gets done it will send msg to respective user

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more using a code ?

Comment: if you liked my answer pls mark it as verified answer